# What constitutes infallibility of Quran?

Tags: quran, infallability

Muslims regard the Quran as infallible and containing in itself evidence of its own veracity (correct me if wrong).  I have read many claims that attribute that status to a lack of contradictions of accounts that are conveyed within the book.  However, I do not understand why an absence of contradictions within a book should designate it as divine.  I find that it would be rather easy for a human to write a book of such closely crafted content whereby no two ideas or positions presented would be conflicting one another.

In that case, what is it exactly that constitutes the revered infallibility of the Quran?

Answer (score 1):

By infallibility of the Quran, it's referring to the perfection of the Arabic language, its linguistic and literary features that are unparalleled and no one can reproduce anything like it. That's the true miracle and challenge.

We can try to find, what we perceive as, contradictions or scientific errors, but that's not the premises for its infallibility and being inimitable.

**قُل لَّئِنِ اجْتَمَعَتِ الْإِنسُ وَالْجِنُّ عَلَىٰ أَن يَأْتُوا بِمِثْلِ هَٰذَا الْقُرْآنِ لَا يَأْتُونَ بِمِثْلِهِ وَلَوْ كَانَ بَعْضُهُمْ لِبَعْضٍ ظَهِيرًا
Say: Verily, though mankind and the jinn should assemble to produce the like of this Quran, they could not produce the like thereof though they were helpers one of another.** (Quran 17:88)

Comment: But how can you "reproduce" any work by man even ?

Comment: Also, why does literary or linguistic elegance merit divinity ?  There are many other works of literature that are written in perfect languages yet do not claim being a work of God

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to the fact that in the Islamic tradition the Qu'ran is a text revealed to a Prophet (*Nabi*) and Messenger (*Rasul*) by Allah.

In a sense, the infallibility of the Qu'ran is referring to the perfection of Allah.

Comment: yes but what proof within the book exists to serve that "infallibility" ?  anyone or anything that claims infallibility ought to demonstrate a reasoning to support that claim

Comment: Not particularly - you're confusing religous notions of infallibility, and what it means and signifies there with a different notion.

Comment: well, your answer is poor because i asked what constitutes [infallibility](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infallibility) which clearly denotes "perfection" or "faultlessness".  your "answer" does not amount to an explanation

Comment: If you take a closer look at my answer and your comment you might just notice why your comment isn't any different from what I said; then again you might not.

Answer (score 0):

Some try to rejoice at the miracles of it which are on par with the scientific discoveries, some just get a very strong feeling that this is [indeed from God](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=3&verse=7). Some cry while reading it, while some others are just amazed by it's style.

A few others even if they haven't read it consider it infallible because they just believe and have faith in it. There are many reasons and any individual can feel differently at different occasions and can have different perspectives about it. These are some some of the reasons I could come up with and others can add into it.

Allah knows the best.

Comment: "I guess, it is simply the faith in Qur'an that constitutes the revered infallibility of the Quran." -- but why do you have faith in the Quran exactly and not some other religion or book that are similarly founded in dogma and not reason ?  is it because you were maybe born into it or is there a more profound reason ?

Comment: what is the 'scientifically error free' property of the Qur'an?  please explain how it is scientifically error free while other books are not

Comment: I wrote a big answer just to answer your first comment "Why faith?". It may be as a result of one or many reasons (aforementioned) together influence a person's faith in a particular religion. Second, 'scientifically error free' property of it? There's a whole [debate](http://www.bing.com/search?q=scientifically+correct+quran&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=scientifically+correct+quran&sc=2-20&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=B464898115ED43E38C3024C70A18B282) going between Dr. Zakir Naik and others, I can't conclude yes or no.